# Find where javascript variable is defined

Tags: javascript, debugging, scope

I am working on a project that is not mine. I want to see where a javascript object is defined but I can't seem to find it. Is there a tool that can help me debug this kind of problem? I tried to find it via linux command `find -type f|xargs grep "name_of_the_class"` but I could not find it.

The project is CMS software and uses jquery and yahoo libraries as well as custom code. I need to see where an obejct is defined because on my development version it is undefined but on the working version it is defined.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: `[Ctrl]+[F]` for `"var myVariable"` ?

Comment: you should use `find . -type f|xargs grep "name_of_the_variable"`, but not `find -type f|xargs grep "name_of_the_class"`

Comment: @Cerbrus I cant find it that way.

Comment: @worldask ok it is class I gave it as an example

Comment: if you using os X, you can try `mdfind variable_name`

Comment: @worldask well I use linux not OS X